# kafka s3 connector partition using kafka key

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

how can I use kafka msg key as the partition criteria in s3 connector OR
how can I get the key and store it also in the s3 object
Thanks!

Comment: You need to read the docs. You need to create a custom partitioner, here's an example of one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62812932/kafka-connect-s3-sink-connector-with-custom-partitioner-strange-behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Transform to "move" the key to the value, then have both in the same object that is then passed to the partitioner.

https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-transform-archive

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom partitioning of data in S3 with the [Lenses S3 Connector](https://github.com/lensesio/stream-reactor/tree/master/kafka-connect-aws-s3), including by payload fields or metadata (key, headers etc.).

Here's an example config which partitions by a value in key, payload & header:

```
connector.class=io.lenses.streamreactor.connect.aws.s3.sink.S3SinkConnector
connect.s3.kcql=INSERT INTO my-s3-bucket:somePrefix SELECT * FROM sales PARTITIONBY _key.year, _value.product_category, _headers.region STOREAS AVRO PROPERTIES('partition.include.keys' = true)
topics=sales
name= test_s3_sink
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
```

It's explained here:
https://lenses.io/blog/2023/09/open-source-lenses-kafka-s3-connector/